# HTML5 worker farm and updating UI progress counters

Tags: html, web-worker, worker

Is a small sub-worker farm feasible?

Let's say we have 100K URLs that we must test to see which are still active and which are dead, and we are trying to do this as quickly as we can using javascript, *reporting the tally of results in the UI as the work progresses:*

```
  Total URLs processed: ######   Dead URLs Found: ######    Timeouts: #######
```

Can we create a master worker, passing it the 100K URLs, and then that worker in turn would create an array of 100 minion sub-workers, sending each minion an array containing only 1K items, and have each minion do HEAD requests for its list of URLs, reporting back to the master the request status (good, 404, etc) with each request; and the master in turn would periodically post a message back to the main window, where the UI progress counters would get incremented?

**Would the master worker be able to listen to messages from its 100 minions and succcessfully update its local variables with the progress counts as they are reported (total processed, total dead, total timed out) without things getting clobbered? And then, let's say with every 100 urls processed, the master would post these tallies back to the UI?**

Comment: This sounds like "When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." Perhaps javascript and lots of machines running browsers isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: I have many tools. But they're all hammers.  Please enlarge upon the limitations of HTML5.   I know this can be done outside the browser.  And I'm thinking of using one machine, not many.

Comment: For example, when you turn on a new machine, you would like it to start running your code and add itself into the farm of sub-workers. That's not so easy with browsers. You can do it but you need a good reason to go to the trouble. I suspect you will run into a lot of things like this but I don't much care to anticipate all the issues you will find. Just offering some advice.

Comment: @Lee Meader. I think you've misunderstood me. I'm not thinking of a distributed hardware network like the one where people trying to solve complex problems use idle CPU cycles and you can donate your PC's timeslices. This is a HTML5 threading question.  Maybe the word "farm" is what's throwing people off the trail?

Comment: I see. You probably wouldn't fill up the messaging between workers but might fill up the network. I've never tried it so I have no practical advice to offer. Might be worth experimenting with.